# Cambiar resultado SELECT por secuencial

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT N.SNUMERO, I.SNOMBRE, S.SSERVICIO FROM PROC_CEDULA CD
JOIN CAT_NUMINTERV N ON CD.NIDCATNUMINT=N.NIDNUMINT
JOIN CAT_INTERVENCIONES I ON CD.NIDCATINTERVENCION=I.NIDINTERVENCION
JOIN CAT_SERVICIOS S ON CD.NIDCATSERV=S.NIDCATSERVICIO
JOIN CUBO_CONSUMIBLES CC ON CD.NIDCUBOCONSUMIBLE=CC.NIDCUBOCONSUMIBLES
JOIN CAT_TIPOSINSUMO T ON CC.NIDTIPOINSUMO=T.NIDCATTIPOSINSUMO
WHERE CD.NIDANIOCEDULA=9 AND CD.BAPLICASUBSIDIO IS NULL AND CD.BAPLICAFEDERAL IS NOT NULL 
AND N.SNUMERO IN ('121','122','123','124')
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(N.SNUMERO),I.SNOMBRE, S.SSERVICIO;
```

Que de devuelve el siguiente resultado:
[image: Resultado]

Necesito agrupar los resultados de *SSERVICIO* para todo lo que sea consulta, es decir no importa si es de especialidad, subsecuente o de cualquier tipo, me debería devolver algo así:

[image: Resultado deseado]

El problema es que no tengo idea de como hacer eso.

Anexo estructura de tablas en el Join:

PROC_CEDULA
[image: PROC_CEDULA]

CAT_NUMINTERV
[image: CAT_NUMINTERV]

CAT_INTERVENCIONES
[image: CAT_INTERVENCIONES]

CAT_SERVICIOS
[image: CAT_SERVICIOS]

CUBO_CONSUMIBLES
[image: CUBO_CONSUMIBLES]

CAT_TIPOINSUMOS
[image: CAT_TIPOINSUMOS]

Comment: Muestra las estructuras de las tablas para poder ayudarte

Comment: hola @Frankenstainero gracias por su apoyo, he agregado el detalle de las tablas

Comment: agregame un comentario con lo que quieres que haga @OrioonTV

Comment: necesito que la salida sea como en la segunda imagen, donde esta en negritas, pero no se me ocurre como sacarlo de ese modo

Comment: Quieres que te los agrupe por el tipo de servicio

Comment: para los servicios que sean like '%CONSULT%' deberia aparecer el primero con la etiqueta: CONSULTA REFERENCIA y los siguientes CONSULTA SUBSECUENTE n+1 dependiendo los que sean

Comment: Pero debes de enteder mi punto si lo que quieres es que te orden de manera secuencual tu order by solo tienes que poner el campo S.SSERVICIO y hacer un LIKE que te filtre solo las que contengan lo que quieres

Comment: Si entiendo esque se debe hacer tambien el cambio de etiquetas

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que te lo ordene Y TE LO AGRUPE TE QUEDARIA ASI y si solamente quieres los servicios que contenga consulta

```
SELECT  N.SNUMERO, I.SNOMBRE, S.SSERVICIO FROM PROC_CEDULA CD
JOIN CAT_NUMINTERV N ON CD.NIDCATNUMINT=N.NIDNUMINT
JOIN CAT_INTERVENCIONES I ON CD.NIDCATINTERVENCION=I.NIDINTERVENCION
JOIN CAT_SERVICIOS S ON CD.NIDCATSERV=S.NIDCATSERVICIO
JOIN CUBO_CONSUMIBLES CC ON CD.NIDCUBOCONSUMIBLE=CC.NIDCUBOCONSUMIBLES
JOIN CAT_TIPOSINSUMO T ON CC.NIDTIPOINSUMO=T.NIDCATTIPOSINSUMO
WHERE CD.NIDANIOCEDULA=9 AND CD.BAPLICASUBSIDIO IS NULL AND CD.BAPLICAFEDERAL IS NOT NULL 
AND N.SNUMERO IN ('121','122','123','124') AND S.SSERVICIO LIKE '%CONSULT%'
GROUP BY S.SSERVICIO, I.SNOMBRE, N.SNUMERO 
ORDER BY S.SSERVICIO;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta pero me parece que estamos hablando de cosas diferentes

Comment: @OrioonTV por eso te explique anteriormente que te explicaras mejor, sobre lo que querias que hiciera